# no [query] registered for [function_score]

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to create a custom score function for better results.

I want to query where tenant_id is 15 and customer_org_type is OA. Now if the print_address with fuzziness 3 is found, give weight 5 and if registered_name with fuzziness 3 is found, give weight 10. but getting no [query] registered for [function_score] error.

```
GET addresses-index/_search
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10,
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {"bool": {}},
      "boost": "5",
      "functions": [
        {
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "filter": {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                    {"match": {"tenant_id": "15"}},
                    {"match": {"customer_org_type": "LP"}}
                  ]
                }
              },
              "must": [
                {
                  "match": [
                    {
                      "print_address": {
                        "query": "FULL ADDRESS HERE",
                        "fuzziness": 3,
                        "random_score": {},
                        "weight": 5
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "registered_name": {
                        "query": "NAME OF THE COMPANY",
                        "fuzziness": 3,
                        "random_score": {},
                        "weight": 10
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }  
        }
      ],
      "max_boost": 42,
      "score_mode": "max",
      "boost_mode": "multiply",
      "min_score": 42
    }
  }
}
```

following is the query given in the documentation which I used as a reference.

```
GET /_search
{
    "query": {
        "function_score": {
          "query": { "match_all": {} },
          "boost": "5", 
          "functions": [
              {
                  "filter": { "match": { "test": "bar" } },
                  "random_score": {}, 
                  "weight": 23
              },
              {
                  "filter": { "match": { "test": "cat" } },
                  "weight": 42
              }
          ],
          "max_boost": 42,
          "score_mode": "max",
          "boost_mode": "multiply",
          "min_score" : 42
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which ES version are you using?

Comment: ES version 6.7.0

Answer (score 1):

You are getting error because under `function_score` you have use the query as `"query": {"bool": {}}`. Your query should be as below:

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10,
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match": {
                "tenant_id": "15"
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "customer_org_type": "LP"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "boost": "5",
      "functions": [
        {
          "filter": {
            "match": {
              "print_address": {
                "query": "FULL ADDRESS HERE",
                "fuzziness": 3
              }
            }
          },
          "random_score": {},
          "weight": 5
        },
        {
          "filter": {
            "match": {
              "registered_name": {
                "query": "NAME OF THE COMPANY",
                "fuzziness": 3
              }
            }
          },
          "random_score": {},
          "weight": 10
        }
      ],
      "max_boost": 42,
      "score_mode": "max",
      "boost_mode": "multiply",
      "min_score": 42
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: getting the error "reason": "[match] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]",

Comment: Oh, My bad. Wrongly placed `random_score` and `weight` inside `filter` block. Correct the query. Please check.

Comment: thanks! but I found that the boost is applied only for term queries (prefix, range and fuzzy queries are not boosted). ref: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-boost.html

Comment: what should I do if I want to use fuzzy logic as well as boost the results on perticular queries?